# Javascript onclick replace entire inner html of div content

Tags: javascript, replace, onclick, innerhtml

When they click on THEATER it should change to NORMAL with a new function in place

example from:

```js
<div id="links">
<a onClick="refreshStream()" onmouseover="color:red;" style="cursor: pointer;" draggable="false" oncontextmenu="return false;">&nbsp;&nbsp; REFRESH</a>
<a onClick="TheaterMode()" onmouseover="color:red;" style="cursor: pointer;" draggable="false" oncontextmenu="return false;">&nbsp;&nbsp; THEATER</a>
</div>
```

TO:

```js
<div id="links">
<a onClick="refreshStream()" onmouseover="color:red;" style="cursor: pointer;" draggable="false" oncontextmenu="return false;">&nbsp;&nbsp; REFRESH</a>
<a onClick="normalsize()" onmouseover="color:red;" style="cursor: pointer;" draggable="false" oncontextmenu="return false;">&nbsp;&nbsp; NORMAL</a>";
</div>
```

I tried this but it didn't work hopefully someone can help thank you.

```js
<script>
document.getElementById("links").innerHTML = "<a onClick="refreshStream()" onmouseover="color:red;" style="cursor: pointer;" draggable="false" oncontextmenu="return false;">&nbsp;&nbsp; REFRESH</a><a onClick="normalsize()" onmouseover="color:red;" style="cursor: pointer;" draggable="false" oncontextmenu="return false;">&nbsp;&nbsp; NORMAL</a>";
</script>
```

Comment: Where is `refreshStream` and `TheaterMode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified your example a bit. Basically you'll either need to wrap the html you're assigning in `.innerHTML = ...` with single quotes, or use `\` to escape the quotes.

Simplified example:

```js
// escape quotes with backslash
function theaterMode() {
    document.getElementById("links").innerHTML = "<a onclick=\"refreshStream()\" style=\"cursor: pointer;\">&nbsp;&nbsp; REFRESH</a><a onclick=\"normalSize()\" style=\"cursor: pointer;\">&nbsp;&nbsp; NORMAL</a>";
}

// or wrap HTML with single quotes
function normalSize() {
    document.getElementById("links").innerHTML = '<a onclick="refreshStream()" style="cursor: pointer;">&nbsp;&nbsp; REFRESH</a><a onclick="theaterMode()" style="cursor: pointer;">&nbsp;&nbsp; THEATER</a>';
}

function refreshStream() {
    document.getElementById("links").innerHTML = "<a onclick=\"refreshStream()\" style=\"cursor: pointer;\">&nbsp;&nbsp; REFRESH</a><a onclick=\"normalSize()\"  style=\"cursor: pointer;\">&nbsp;&nbsp; NORMAL</a>";
}
```

```html
<div id="links">
    <a onclick="refreshStream()" style="cursor: pointer;">&nbsp;&nbsp; REFRESH</a>
    <a onclick="theaterMode()" style="cursor: pointer;">&nbsp;&nbsp; THEATER</a>
</div>
```

There are cleaner ways to do this, and if you're only changing what the second link does then there's really no reason to keep updating the first link.

Hope that's helpful.

Comment: I'd like to say my thanks and say I appreciate the time you took to explain things. everything became so clear to me once i learned about out single quotes, or the use \ to escape the quotes. (new to JS)

Comment: No problem, glad you got some value from it!